# stopping counter at 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, decrement

I have two functions that increment and decrement number of items by 1, but when I decrement I want to stop at 0? this are the functions

```
const addToCart = (productId) => {
    setCartItems((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [productId]: prev[productId] + 1,
    }));
  };

  const removeToCart = (productId) => {
    setCartItems((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [productId]: prev[productId] - 1,
    }));
  };
```

they are then called in button by onClick action

```
<button
              className="add-btn mx-2"
              onClick={() => {
                addToCart(product.id);
              }}
            >
              {" "}
              +
</button>
<button
              className="add-btn mx-2"
              onClick={() => {
                removeToCart(product.id);
              }}
            >
              {" "}
              -
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to cap the value.

```js
const removeToCart = (productId) => {
    setCartItems((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [productId]: Math.max(prev[productId] - 1, 0),
    }));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just modify removeToCart to look at the value of prev[productId] and if it is less than or equal to 0, then do nothing otherwise do the decrement?